# Vitali convergence and convergence in measure

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Part of the general Vitali's Convergence theorem says:

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions on $E$ that is uniformly integrable and tight over E. If $\{f_n\} \rightarrow f$ ***pointwise a.e.*** on $E$, then $f$ is integrable over $E$.

Now, can ***$\{f_n\} \rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e.*** be removed and replaced with ***$\{f_n\} \rightarrow f$ in measure***?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, convergence in measure implies a.e. convergence along a subsequence.

Comment: So, I can say that if there is a convergence in measure from $f_n$ $\rightarrow$ $f$, there is a subsequence $f_k$ $\rightarrow$ $f$ pointwise almost everywhere, and does that follow that $f$ is integrable?

Comment: What about subsequences of a sequence that is uniformly integrable and tight? Is the subsequence also unifomly integrable and tight?